# I am not sure if my .htaccess is wrong or if the server didn't read my .htaccess file yet

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am pretty certain, that my code is alright, for a briefly moment, my htaccess seems to work when i entered an url. After I extended the file and reuploaded it, my Rule didn't work any more. Even when I removed my edit the Rewrite Rule don't triggert any more.
Did i miss something in my Rule. I don't get it whats wrong right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^www\.sub\.domain\.de\/(.*)\.html$ www.sub.domain.de/typo3/$1.html?&%{QUERY_STRING}


</IfModule>
```

Comment: The first parameter of the `RewriteRule` should omit the URL part corresponding to the place where the .htaccess file is: if your file is in the root of `www.sub.domain.de/`, it should be: RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$

Comment: Now i shorten the regex a bit like your example.
`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.de\/(.*)\.html$ $1/typo3/$2.html?&%{QUERY_STRING} `
Is my RewriteRule so far correct? I am really new in htaccess, so i am unsure if my code is wrong or if it's some Serversided limitations.

Comment: No. The domain (`www.sub.domain.de/`) will always be missing from the string to test for the first parameter. Your rule simply won't match. Try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ www.sub.domain.de/typo3/$1.html?&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: It kinda works, but now i have the problem that the code does a recursive call. So I have a url that looks like sub.domain.de/typo3/[...]/typo3/index.html

Comment: You can try to add `[QSA,L]` at the end (after a space). `QSA` means the query string will be transmitted, and `L` that there will be the last rewrite/redirection applied. In case you have a problem with your query strings, try to remove `?&%{QUERY_STRING}`, `QSA` is supposed to be enough for it to be preserved

Answer (score 0):

Okay. My first mistake was the complete url as first param in RewriteRule. 
After I followed Kaddath's instuctions the rewrite kinda worked. I still had a problem with a loop call. The htaccess appendes planty "typo3/typo3/...", so that a RewriteCondition has to solve this. I checked if the url has already typo3 in his string. Now the Url is correctly rewritten. 
I also tried [L] before to stop a looping rewriteRule, but it didn't help.

Thank you Kaddath for giving the right clues.

Comment: You're welcome, however, you should add the final code to the answer for it to be useful for future readers